# how to make data into the same row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like this

```
id event 2015 2016 2017
   a 2015   33    na  na
   a  2016   na    32  na
   a 2017   na    na  31
   b 2015   30    na  na
   b 2017   na    na   20
```

how do I make all the non-missing values in the same row:

```
id   2015   2016   2017
 a   33     32     31
 b   30     0      20
```

sorry the questions above do not solve my case, and the code does not work

Comment: give code to reproduce

Comment: So you need `df = df.replace('na', np.nan).groupby('id', as_index=False).first().fillna(0)` ?

Comment: 1) I need to groupy id 2)within same id, I want 2015, 2016, 2017 all on the same row. For example, under id a, I want 2015 with 33, 2016 with 32, and 2017 with 31 in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df = df.set_index('event').replace('na', np.nan)
df1 = pd.concat([df[col].dropna() for col in df.columns], axis=0).to_frame().T
```

---

**df1:**

```
event   2015    2016    2017
0       33      32      31
```

1st replace `na` by `NaN` then set event as index. Dropall the `NaN` from the column values.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for first non missing value per groups by `id`:

```
df = (df.drop('event', axis=1)
        .replace('na', np.nan)
        .groupby('id', as_index=False)
        .first()
        .fillna(0))
print (df)
  id 2015 2016 2017
0  a   33   32   31
1  b   30    0   20
```